# var undefined in javascript console.log()

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
app.get('/account', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res){
  res.render('account', { user: req.user });
  console.log(req.user);
});
```

I have the following code in javascript. It renders to an EJS file where i'm able to display properties like user.id and user.displayname. But when i try to see its value locally, it says undefined. Any idea?

Comment: can you just log the `req` object and see what is logged

Comment: yes its huge. too big for this site. so many parameters. The point is that req.user is assigned to user and then properties are displayed of it in the EJS file. I want to get those properties in the JS file

Comment: you don't have to post the complete result... but whether the user property is visible there.... also try to log `console.log(Object.keys(req))`

Comment: Another option is to put `req` into JSON before logging it: `console.log(JSON.stringify(req))`